# React/Nodejs: URLs on front-end and back-end don't match , which causes an error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

I want to create a public profile page in my application, but whenever I hit a route, an error appears in the console. I can't understand what a problem is, could you please look at it with your fresh eyes. Let me give you more info about my issue.

**Public route - back-end**

```
// @route  POST api/profile/user/:user_id
// @desc   Get profile by user ID
// @access Public
router.get('/user/:user_id', (req, res) => {
  const errors = {};
  Profile.findOne({ user: req.params.user_id })
    .populate('user', ['name', 'email', 'avatar'])
    .then(profile => {
      if (!profile) {
        errors.nonprofile = 'There is no profile for this user';
        res.status(404).json(errors);
      }
      res.json(profile);
    })
    .catch(err =>
      res.status(404).json({ profile: 'There is no profile for this user' })
    );
});
```

**Redux action part**

```
export const getPublicProfileByID = id => dispatch => {
  console.log(id);
  axios
    .get(`api/profile/user/${id}`)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_PUBLIC_PROFILE_BY_ID,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_PUBLIC_PROFILE_BY_ID,
        payload: null
      })
    );
};
```

**PublicProfile - react part**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Spinner from '../common/Spinner';
import { getPublicProfileByID } from '../../actions/profileActions';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class PublicProfile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.getPublicProfileByID(this.props.profile._id);
  }

  render() {
    const { profile, loading } = this.props.profile;
    const { auth } = this.props;
    console.log(profile);
    let profileShow;

    if (profile === null || loading) {
      profileShow = <Spinner />;
    } else {
      profileShow = (
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-4" align="center">
            <figure className="figure">
              <img
                src={auth.user.avatar}
                className="figure-img img-fluid rounded"
                alt={auth.user.avatar}
              />
            </figure>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-6">{profile.bio}</div>
          <div className="col-md-2">
            <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li className="list-group-item">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col">
                    {profile.social ? (
                      <a href={profile.social.facebook} target="_blank">
                        <i className="fab fa-facebook" />
                      </a>
                    ) : null}
                  </div>
                  <div className="col">
                    {profile.social ? (
                      <a href={profile.social.vk} target="_blank">
                        <i className="fab fa-vk" />
                      </a>
                    ) : null}
                  </div>
                  <div className="col">
                    {profile.social ? (
                      <a href={profile.social.instagram} target="_blank">
                        <i className="fab fa-instagram" />
                      </a>
                    ) : null}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              {profile.country ? (
                <li className="list-group-item">Страна: {profile.country}</li>
              ) : null}
              {profile.city ? (
                <li className="list-group-item">Город: {profile.city}</li>
              ) : null}
              {profile.gender ? (
                <li className="list-group-item">Пол: {profile.gender}</li>
              ) : null}
              {profile.education ? (
                <li className="list-group-item">
                  Образование: {profile.education}
                </li>
              ) : null}
              {profile.languages ? (
                <li className="list-group-item">
                  Языки:{' '}
                  {profile.languages.map(language => (
                    <span key={language}>{language}</span>
                  ))}
                </li>
              ) : null}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col align-self-center">{profileShow}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

PublicProfile.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  getPublicProfileByID: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  profile: state.profile,
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getPublicProfileByID }
)(PublicProfile);
```

**Redux Reducer Part**

```
import {
  GET_PROFILE,
  PROFILE_LOADING,
  CLEAR_CURRENT_PROFILE,
  GET_PUBLIC_PROFILE_BY_ID
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  profile: null,
  profiles: null,
  loading: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PROFILE_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case GET_PROFILE:
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case GET_PUBLIC_PROFILE_BY_ID:
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case CLEAR_CURRENT_PROFILE:
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: null
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Public route in app.js**

```
<Route exact path="/leaders/:id" component={PublicProfile} />
```

**URL in the browser**
[image]

**Error in the console**
[image]

Comment: whats the port your nodejs server is running, as 3000 the one you are calling is react default port not your backend port

Comment: All other routes work fine. So I guess the problem is not with ports.

Comment: If other routes are working fiene then, while quering your useId is undefined and in that case you are sending 404 see the catch section of your backend

Comment: What Leader are doin Here, `.get(api/profile/user/${id})`, and you are hitting `/leader/api/profile/user/`

Comment: There is no console.log(id) seen on console, id is not getting set to specific data.

Comment: Yes exactly, I can't undestand how leader got there because it should be just
'/api/profile/user/:id'. I have not specified anything like that in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, I should have used `findById` method, and params should have been `req.params.id`. So a valid code looks like this.

```
// @route  POST api/profile/user/:user_id
// @desc   Get profile by user ID
// @access Public

router.get('/user/:id', (req, res) => {
  const errors = {};
  Profile.findById(req.params.id)
    .populate('user', ['name', 'email', 'avatar'])
    .then(profile => {
      if (!profile) {
        errors.nonprofile = 'There is no profile for this user';
        res.status(404).json(errors);
      }
      res.json(profile);
    })
    .catch(err =>
      res.status(404).json({ profile: 'There is no profile for this user' })
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing your front end `URL` with backend `Restful http URL`,
you need to start different two ports for both react and node app,
You are mixing logic of React-Route with node-Express logic,
when `localhost:3000` stands for react,
you should choose different port number for backend app,
keep server listening on that port,
then make req to that urls and communicate your data.
You need to configure your app properly.
eg.
`localhost:3000/leaders/leader/2` for your front end,
make server request like,
`localhost:8000/api/profile/user/2` where 2 is `${id}` for backend code.

Answer (score 1):

Just one issue I noticed, in your api route, it wants to find a `Profile` who's `user` field matches the parameter you passed.

```
router.get('/user/:user_id', (req, res) => {
  const errors = {};
  Profile.findOne({ user: req.params.user_id })
```

However it looks like you are passing in the wrong value in your action-creator. You're passing in the id of the profile.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.getPublicProfileByID(this.props.profile._id);
  }
```

Instead, you need to pass in the id of the user who owns this profile.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.getPublicProfileByID(this.props.profile.user._id);
  }
```

Second, there appears to be an error with your `axios` call

```
  axios
    .get(`api/profile/user/${id}`)
```

Comment: if I put user there it throws an error: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined.

Comment: Why my url looks like this:
http://localhost:3000/api/profile/user/5cf2828fb3ae541c8491634b 404 (Not Found),
instead it should look like this:
http://localhost:3000/api/user/5cf2828fb3ae541c8491634b 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @NZMAI, wait but in your route definition you commented the following for your route //route  POST api/profile/user/:user_id  <--- isnt that what you want?

Comment: plese upvote and accept  @ChristopherNgo 's answer if it worked.

Comment: Yes, but I think, 'profile' between api and user, does not allow me to proceed. Ho it happened to be there?

Comment: @NZMAI what do you mean? Your profile route is explicitly /api/profile/user/:user_id. Thats what you defined, and thats the route you're hitting on axios request :)... quite strange, all your other routes seem to work so I dont see why this one would be any different.

Comment: That's true, it does not event call the action, it did though, before I changed my code, but anyway it throwed an error. It drives me crazy)